# My Floating-point problem - Trial in C++/Python

Tags: python, c++, floating-point, ieee-754

In what follows, IEEE-754 Double-precision floating-point format is taken for granted to be used.

[Python:](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html) "...almost all machines use IEEE 754 binary floating-point arithmetic, and almost all platforms map Python floats to IEEE 754 binary64 'double precision' values."

[C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_epsilon): associates `double` with IEEE-754 double-precision.

Machine epsilon is s.t. fl(1+epsilon)>1.

Using double precision, *formally* epsilon = 2^-52, but mostly implemented (because of rounding-to-nearest) as epsilon = 2^-53.

In Python (Spyder), when I do:

```
i = 1.0 + 2**-53

print(i)

>> 1.0
```

C++ version:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
    
int main() {
        
    double i = std::pow(2.0, -53);
        
    double j = 1.0 + i;
        
    std::cout << j;
    
    return 0;
        
}

>> 1.0
```

Furthermore, when I do in Python:

```
i = 1.0 + 2**-52 + 2**-53

print(i)

>> 1.0000000000000004
```

C++ version:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <iomanip>
        
int main() {
                
    double i = std::pow(2.0, -52);
                
    double j = 1.0 + i;
                
    double k = j + std::pow(2.0, -53);
                
    std::cout << std::setprecision(17) << k;
        
    return 0;

}
    
>> 1.0000000000000004
```

where the order of addition is from left to right so that the magic of the non-associativity does not come into play, i.e.

`i = 1.0 + 2**-52 + 2**-53 <=> i = (1.0 + 2**-52) + 2**-53`.

The weird (to me) thing happens here. Firstly, 1 + 2**-52 is **stored** (in registers) as **exactly** the Double Precision format equivalent of 1 + 2*epsilon, i.e.

```
0 + 01111111111 + 000...01
```

Moreover, 2**-53 is stored as:

```
0 + 01111001010 + 000...00
```

If we write these in the form `(mantissa)*(2**exponent)`, `1 + 2**-52` is `(1.0000...01)*(2**0)`, and `2**-53` is `(1.0000...00)*(2**-53)`, where the mantissa (1.xxxx...xx) length is 53 (including implicit 1 bit). A bitwise addition requires the same exponent, thus I shift the mantissa of the smaller one (i.e. 2**-53) so that it has exponent 0:

```
(1.0000...00)*(2**-53) -> (0.|52 zeros here|10000...00)*(2**0)
```

So that the addition is like:

```
1.0000...010 (51 zero digits after the radix, then a '1' and '0' making a total of 53 digits)
0.0000...001 (52 zero digits after the radix + '1' digit making a total of 53 digits)
+
------------
1.0000...011 (53 digits after the radix)
```

Now, mantissa should be 53 in total, but it is 54 above, thus it should be rounded.

**My question begins here:** Is the reason why both of these programming languages give `1.0000000000000004` output when I do `1.0 + 2**-52 + 2**-53` because **tie-to-even** rule is implemented so that  `1.0000...011` is rounded to `1.0000...10`, which is esentially `1.0000000000000004` up to 16 digits precision? or is it (completely) something else & I made a mistake in the calculations etc.?

Sorry if it seems as a bit of overkill or overthinking on a simple subject like this, however, it bothers me for days and I could not figure out the reason why or could not verify my thoughts. Any answer and comment is appreciated.

Comment: Side note: `std::setprecision(17)` put you a few digits into the floating point fuzz zone. You can't, in the general case, count on sane results much past 15 digits.

Comment: @user4581301 I have thought about this but I think it shouldn't be a problem here. Thanks for pointing out though.

Comment: `double k = k + std::pow(2.0, -53);` should be `double k = j + std::pow(2.0, -53);`

Comment: With 2-to-the X, I'd agree. such numbers should be representable until you shoot off the end of what `double` can handle, but 1+2-to-the-X is a different form of ugly, so I figured it was worth bringing up.

Comment: @user4581301 every binary number has an exact decimal equivalent, and it often takes a lot more than 15 digits to get to the end of it.

Comment: The tie-to-even rule is not imposed by the C++ standard (nor, IIRC but haven't checked, Python specs).   It is typically a result of how IEEE floating point operations are implemented in hardware.   [The C++ standard doesn't actually mandate IEEE floating point either, although some library features are clearly specified with IEEE in mind].

Comment: Re “A bitwise addition requires the same exponent” and “mantissa should be 53 in total, but it is 54 above”: IEEE 754 does not specify **how** arithmetic is performed. Whether an implementation adjusts the exponents and shifts the significands (not mantissas) or how many intermediate bits it keeps for rounding is up to the implementation. IEEE 754 specifies **what the results should be**. The results of elementary operations are **as if** the operation were performed with infinite precision and then rounded according to the rounding rule in effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's entirely about round-to-nearest/even. Python's `float.hex()` can show you the bits directly:

```py
>>> 1.0 + 2**-52 + 2**-53
1.0000000000000004
>>> _.hex()
'0x1.0000000000002p+0'
```

Although Python and C have little to do with this: it's almost certainly a result of how your CPU/FPU implement float addition (they almost certainly implement 754-style nearest/even rounding in hardware by default).
``
Note too that associativity doesn't matter in this specific example. `1.0 + 2**-52` and `2**-52 + 2**-53` are both exactly representable on their own.

Comment: The only reason I have mentioned about associativity was to emphasize left to right computation since the other way around gives entirely different results. You are right that it is not necessary though.

Comment: Commutativity _does_ matter in this example: rearranging to `(1.0 + 2**-53) + 2**-52` gives a different result (because `1.0 + 2**-53` on its own is not exactly representable, and rounds down to exactly 1.0). Associativity is a different thing.

Comment: Associativity is (x+y)+z = x+(y+z), ain't it?

Comment: Right. The example I gave in the comment shows a failure of `(a+b)+c = (a+c)+b`, which isn't _just_ a ,matter of parentheses. .

Comment: OK, got it. I meant to say *associativity* in the case of `1.0 + 2**-53 + 2**-52`, The case I have written is already associative under addition.

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, ties round to even. That's the default IEEE 754 rounding mode. IEEE 754 defines [4 possible rounding modes](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/floating-point/index.html#rounding-modes):

- Round to nearest, breaking ties toward even.
- Round toward zero.
- Round toward positive infinity.
- Round toward negative infinity.

Picking anything but the default is an extremely specialized operation that most languages don't even support, though.

Comment: IEEE 754 specifies five rounding modes, not four, in clause 4.3. 4.3.1 specifies round to nearest with ties to even and round to nearest with ties to away. 4.3.2 specifies round toward positive, round toward negative, and round toward zero. (And the committee is currently discussing adding more.)

Comment: @EricPostpischil: Is that in one of the later revisions? The actual standard text is paywalled, so I'm going off of secondary sources, and the ones I've found don't cite a specific standard revision.

Comment: It is in 754-2019.